# Mongoose findOne throws unknown error when call findOne too much

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

```
Model.findOne({_id: offer._id}, function (err, doc) {
// Whatever
});
```

When I use `findOne` many times(about 12000) it throws such an error:

```
> openssl config failed: error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such
> process events.js:167
>       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>       ^
> 
> Error: read ECONNRESET
>     at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27) Emitted 'error' event at:
>     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:391:9)
>     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
>     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
>     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

I don't know how to handle this error and why this happens, Google’s searches did not help. This error only occurs when I use the method `findOne`.

Comment: It appears that your database connection is getting reset when you fire large number of queries. You should be able to handle this by registering an error event handler on the original connection returned from mongoose.createConnection call.

Comment: Can you please give me some example, I don't really understand how to realize this properly?

Comment: `process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) { // Prevent uncaughtException Error: read ECONNRESET
    console.error(err.stack);
});` I did it this way in my db.js file, it seems to be working